# Xslt 1.0 apply-templates on a variable node-set changes root node

Tags: xml, xslt

I have a xslt template and I was trying to segment all the logic for my items into different files and templates so everything would be nice and neat. I am using Microsofts xslt processor btw.

Well, I ran into this problem where I call apply-template on a variable that is a node-set and the node-set becomes root xml node.

```
<xsl:import href="tblLogins.xslt"/>
<xsl:import href="tblPay_OrderItems.xslt/>



            <xsl:variable name="item" select="/Entities/Data/tblLogins"/>
            <!-- Get the users orders -->
            <xsl:variable name="_orders" >
                <xsl:apply-templates select="$item" mode="GetOrders" />
            </xsl:variable>
            <xsl:variable name="orders" select="msxsl:node-set($_orders)/*" />
            <!-- Get the order's items -->
            <!-- This works and we now have all the orders -->
            <xsl:variable name="_orderItems" >
                <xsl:apply-templates select="$orders" mode="GetOrderItems" />
            </xsl:variable>
            <xsl:variable name="orderItems" select="msxsl:node-set($_orderItems)/*" />
            <!-- will always be empty -->
```

tblLogins.xslt

```
<xsl:key name="ordersByUserId" match="tblPay_Orders" use="UserId" />

<xsl:template match="tblLogins" mode="GetOrders" >
    <xsl:copy-of select="key('ordersByUserId',loginID)"/>
</xsl:template>
```

tblPay_Order.xslt

```
<xsl:key name="orderItemsByOrderId" match="tblPay_OrderItems" use="OrderId" />

<xsl:template match="tblPay_Orders" mode="GetOrderItems" >
    <!-- "/" is now the tblPay_Orders and nothing else is available -->
    <xsl:copy-of select="key('orderItemsByOrderId',Id)"/>
    <!-- will return nothing -->
</xsl:template>
```

Without Templates

```
<!-- Works -->
<xsl:copy-of select="key('orderItemsByOrderId',key('ordersByUserId',loginID)/Id)"/>
```

EDIT: I have it set up in different files right now. I did take all of the files and copy paste them into the one xslt and this still happened.

Now, If I undo the templates and just have a list of Key('',key('',key(''.....etc it will work because "/" contains everything still. But when I apply templates, this happens.

I saw the question [XSLT: Process an Xml node set in a template while still having access to the document root](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3109466/xslt-process-an-xml-node-set-in-a-template-while-still-having-access-to-the-doc) which is a way to get around it. But my question is more of a why does this even happen and how is it handled in XSLT 2.0? (even though MS will never update to 2.0)

I thought that in XSLT 2.0 the result tree fragment was done away with. Is there still a "Result Tree Fragment" like object, but it now supports "/" operations and such? or is everything a node-set?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trouble is that the nodes in your `_orders` variable aren't the original nodes from the input document but rather newly created *copies* of those nodes in a result tree fragment. The `msxsl:node-set` function turns this RTF into a single document root node (in XPath data model terms - in DOM terms it's a document fragment) with the copied `tblPay_Orders` elements as its children.

So when you `apply-templates` to these nodes you're changing the current document to this fragment, so `/` then refers to the fragment node rather than the original document root (more precisely, a path of `/` refers to the root node of whichever document the current context node belongs to), and the `key` function looks up nodes in the fragment.

You would have exactly the same issue in XSLT 2.0 if you used the same template (XSLT 2.0 calls it a "temporary tree" rather than a RTF but the principle is the same) - `copy-of` still creates new nodes in a temporary tree. But you could use `xsl:sequence` instead:

```
<xsl:template match="tblLogins" mode="GetOrders" >
    <xsl:sequence select="key('ordersByUserId',loginID)"/>
</xsl:template>
```

The difference here is that `xsl:sequence` returns the original nodes attached to the original document rather than creating temporary copies in a new tree.

Comment: Arg. It makes sense, but it still sucks that I can't really organize it the way I would like.

Answer (score -1):

Read about the `<xsl:import>` and `<xsl:include>` instructions.

http://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xslt-19991116#import

and:

http://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xslt-19991116#include